# Why would you need unsigned types in Java?

Tags: java, language-design

I have often heard complaints against Java for not having unsigned data types. See for example [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25492/is-java-viable-for-serious-game-development/25512#comment43373_25494) comment. I would like to know how is this a problem? I have been programming in Java for 10 years more or less and never had issues with it. Occasionally when converting bytes to ints a `& 0xFF` is needed, but I don't consider that as a problem.

Since unsigned and signed numbers are represented with the same bit values, the only places I can think of where signedness matters are:

- When converting the numbers to other bit representation. Between 8, 16 and 32 bit integer types you can use bitmasks if needed.
- When converting numbers to decimal format, usually to Strings.
- Interoperating with non-Java systems through API's or protocols. Again the data is just bits, so I don't see the problem here.
- Using the numbers as memory or other offsets. With 32 bit ints this might be problem for very huge offsets.

Instead I find it easier that I don't need to consider operations between unsigned and signed numbers and the conversions between those. What am I missing? What are the actual benefits of having unsigned types in a programming language and how would having those make Java better?

Comment: FYI: `/`, `%`, `<`, and `>` all have different interpretations for signed and unsigned values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Occasionally when converting bytes to ints a & 0xFF is needed, but I don't consider that as a problem.

Why not? Is "applying a bitwise AND with 0xFF" actually part of what your code is trying to represent? If not, why should it have to be part of have you write it? I actually find that almost *anything* I want to do with bytes beyond just copying them from one place to another ends up requiring a mask. I want my code to be cruft-free; the lack of unsigned bytes hampers this :(

Additionally, consider an API which will *always* return a non-negative value, or only *accepts* non-negative values. Using an unsigned type allows you to express that clearly, without any need for validation. Personally I think it's a shame that unsigned types aren't used *more* in .NET, e.g. for things like `String.Length`, `ICollection.Count` etc. It's very common for a value to naturally only be non-negative.

Is the lack of unsigned types in Java a fatal flaw? Clearly not. Is it an annoyance? Absolutely.

The comment that you quote hits the nail on the head:

> Java's lack of unsigned data types also stands against it. Yes, you can work around it, but it's not ideal and you'll be using code that doesn't really reflect the underlying data correctly.

Suppose you *are* interoperating with another system, which wants an unsigned 16 bit integer, and you want to represent the number 65535. You claim "the data is just bits, so I don't see the problem here" - but having to pass -1 to mean 65535 *is* a problem. Any impedance mismatch between the representation of your data and its underlying meaning introduces an extra speedbump when writing, reading and testing the code.

> Instead I find it easier that I don't need to consider operations between unsigned and signed numbers and the conversions between those.

The only times you would *need* to consider those operations is when you were naturally working with values of two different types - one signed and one unsigned. At that point, you *absolutely* want to have that difference pointed out. With signed types being used to represent naturally unsigned values, you *should* still be considering the differences, but the fact that you should is hidden from you. Consider:

```
// This should be considered unsigned - so a value of -1 is "really" 65535
short length = /* some value */;
// This is really signed
short foo = /* some value */;

boolean result = foo < length;
```

Suppose `foo` is 100 and `length` is -1. What's the *logical* result? The value of `length` *represents* 65535, so logically `foo` is smaller than it. But you'd probably go along with the code above and get the wrong result.

Of course they don't even need to represent *different* types here. They could both be naturally unsigned values, represented as signed values with negative numbers being logically greater than positive ones. The same error applies, and *wouldn't* be a problem if you had unsigned types in the language.

You might also want to read [this interview with Joshua Bloch](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aU2dQLJSDtasJ%3ajava.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/bloch_effective_08_qa.html&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1) (Google cache, as I believe it's gone from java.sun.com now), including:

> Ooh, good question... I'm going to say that the strangest thing about the Java platform is that the byte type is signed. I've never heard an explanation for this. It's quite counterintuitive and causes all sorts of errors.

Comment: If it helps, Guava has been [adding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/package-summary.html) some support for treating values as unsigned.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: It certainly helps - but it's a workaround compared with it being in the language :(

Comment: Instead of -1 I just write (short)65535, a minor annoyance.

Comment: With unsigned array indices reversed for-loops are evil. for (uint i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) doesn't work directly. This has annoyed me more than the bitmasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It explains the problems well. Still, I don't think any of these problems are that bad. As you said yourself, they are an annoyance. I still would not prefer unsigned types to be added to Java, since the lack of those doesn't limit anything, only makes expressing some things more difficult. I am more annoyed in C when needing to convert between unsigned and signed, as that happens quite often. For example subtracting two unsigned values or restricting array indices to unsigned values, but then needing to mark invalid index with -1.

Comment: @msell: Maybe we shouldn't have `long` either. After all, you can do it all using two `int` values. Heck, why bother with anything other than a single `bit` type? If you want more than one bit, use an array of them. It would only be an annoyance, right? I think it's probably too late to add unsigned types to Java *now*, as a bunch of the natural uses for them are already in place with signed types. But I still think it's a shame they aren't in there. I believe very firmly that the more accurately you can represent your underlying data in the type system, the clearer your code is.

Answer (score 2):

If you like, yes, everything is ones and zeroes. However, your hardware arithmetic and logic unit doesn't work that way. If you want to store your bits in a signed integer value but perform operations that are not natural to signed integers, you will usually waste both storage space and processing time.

An unsigned integer type stores twice as many non-negative values in the same space as the corresponding signed integer type. So if you want to take into Java any data commonly used in a language with unsigned values, such as a POSIX date value (unsigned number of seconds) that is normally used with C, then in general you will need to use a wider integer type than C would use. If you are processing many such values, again you will waste both storage space and fetch-execute time.

Answer (score 0):

The times I have used unsigned data types have been when I read in large blocks of data that correspond to images, or worked with openGL.  I personally prefer unsigned if I know something will never be negative, as a "safety feature" of sorts.

Unsigned types are useful for bit-by-bit comparisons, and I'm pretty sure they are used extensively in graphics.